# Como comprobar si una variable ya existe en una database?

Tags: java, javafx

estoy usando la libreria sqlite para conectarme a una base de datos y quiero comprobar si una identifiacion de un usuario ya existe. Como podria comprobarlo? He intentado usando

```
ResultSet rse = sta.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM usuarios");
allIdVector[] = rse.getString(1);
if(allIdVector.contains(id)){
Sytem.out.print("El usuario ya existe")
}
```

Basicamente lo que quiero es:

```
(si id  ya esta en la columna ids de una bd){
    imprimir(Error, ya existe un usuario con esa id)
}
```

Comment: sera que queres comprobar que un dato exista en una tabla dentro de una base de datos? una vez dicho eso, si no le pones un where a tu consulta, siempre va a traer todo... esto es igual para cualquier base de datos...

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una respuesta, solo hay que hacer un Query buscando dicha id, despues verificar si `Resulset.next()` devulve true, si lo hace ya existe, si devuelve false el id no existe

```
ResultSet rse = sta.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id='" + idaBuscar + "'");

if (rse.next())
   ingerrfield.setText("Error, ya existe un paciente con esa identificación");
```